# Review structure of PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, beginner, html5

I am very new to PHP and I kind of sort of want to create the pages like I would in ASP.NET; it's just the way I am wired.  I have been inserting the header/menu using a PHP Include  and here is what the code looks like for just the first page.

Am I doing this properly, or is there a better way?

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>New Jerusalem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">
        <?php include ('Menu.php') ?>
      </div>
    <div id="content">
      <h1 class="PageTitle" >Sturgis Hellfighters</h1>
        <div class="indexright" width="50%">
          <h3 class="smallheader">Scripture Corner</h3>
          <p><img src="images/Romans5-8.jpg" width="475" alt="Romans 5:8" /></p>
          <p></p>

        </div>
        <div class="indexleft" width="50%">
          <p><img src="images/BridalFallsSpearfishCanyon.jpg" width="475" height="720" alt="Bridal Falls Spearfish Canyon" />
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Menu.php**

```
<img src="images/SiteHeader.jpg" width="1000" height="150" alt="HellFighters New Jerusalem" id="siteheader"/>
<ul id="HomeMenu">
    <li class="TopLevel"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="TopLevel"><a href="#">News</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="SecondLevel"><a href="#">Sturgis Current Events</a></li>
            <li class="SecondLevel"><a href="#">Rapid City Events</a></li>
            <li class="SecondLevel"><a href="#">Pierre Events</a></li>
            <li class="SecondLevel"><a href="#">Other Events</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="TopLevel"><a href="#">Photos</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="SecondLevel"><a href="christmasatpineridge.php">Christmas On Pine Ridge</a></li>
            <li class="SecondLevel"><a href="XmasMission.php">Christmas At the Mission</a></li>
            <li class="SecondLevel"><a href="OpenHouse.php">Open House</a></li>
            <li class="SecondLevel"><a href="Nationals.php">Nationals</a>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li class="TopLevel"><a href="#">Events</a>
        <ul> <!--  -->
            <li class="SecondLevel"><a href="#">A Pine Ridge Christmas</a>
            <li class="SecondLevel"><a href="#">A Sturgis HellFighter Christmas</a>
            <li class="SecondLevel"><a href="#">Sturgis Motorcycle Rally</a></li>
            <li class="SecondLevel"><a href="#">Random City Swap Meet</a></li>
            <li class="SecondLevel"><a href="#">Cool Event</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
    <li class="TopLevel"><a href="#">Contact Info</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="SecondLevel"><a href="#">President</a></li>
            <li class="SecondLevel"><a href="#">Vice-President</a></li>
            <li class="SecondLevel"><a href="#">Preacher Man</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>    
</ul>
```

---

I would like to use HTML5 if possible, so if your review brings up HTML5 that is cool with me too.

---

If you would like to see the front page, [click here](http://sturgishellfighters.hartwebpages.com).

**This page will be changing as I am currently working on it.**

Comment: I was surprised to see that you had a working example, `<?php include ('Menu.php') ?>` I would think would generate a fatal error with the semicolon.

Comment: @Pickett what do you mean? because I didn't put a semicolon at the end? I was following some examples. they could have been old examples...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Your syntax [is OK](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php), however I would still end each statement with a semicolon.

Comment: @Pickett I agree, I like Semicolons.

Comment: Pedantic note/tip: if `menu.php` doesn't contain any PHP, then change its extension to what it really is: `html`. The php extension means your sever is passing the file to the PHP parser first, which doesn't do anything but take up more resources & slowing you down. the PHP extension is only required for files that contain code

Comment: Thank you. I thought if it was going to be called by a php file it had to be a php file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Going to some HTML5 stuff straight away.

1. Replace your doctype with the HTML5 doctype. This is necessary for the next few steps

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   ```
2. Use the shorter charset meta tag and the meta viewport tag inside your head area. The viewport meta tag is necessary for mobile devices and ensures  a good default viewport.

   ```
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   ```

   *Side note*: *You may omit the `type`-attribute for style, script and link tag (not for RSS) and the closing `/` for self-closing tags. **This is not a  recommendation**, but it's possible.*
3. Use ID's only when you definitely can say "There will be only one element of this per page, ever". A *wrapper* is not unique to a page. It should be a class.

   Generally speaking, ID's don't provide you with a true benefit and kinda makes your life harder. I don't use ID's as  styling hooks anymore and I'm really happy with it.
4. You're navigation is included with PHP and is named `menu.php`, but it actually contains a header image as well. A better name would be `header.php`, wouldn't it?

   That being said, you may consider moving everything above your header and the header itself to a `header.php`. Even your head area and the html tag. This is only usable, if you your header is the same on all of your pages.
5. I'm using dash-delmited class names in my HTML. No CamelCase names. This is my preference and if you want to use CamelCase, this is fine. However I would avoid using no delimiting and lowercase names like `indexright` or `smallheader`.

That's it for now. I'll going to edit some more stuff later. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to kleinfreund suggestions :

1. For a link to the homepage, i'd rather do

   ```
   <a href="/">Home</a>
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   <a href="index.php">Home</a>
   ```

   as http://sturgishellfighters.hartwebpages.com/ is a cleaner URL than http://sturgishellfighters.hartwebpages.com/index.php
2. If you care about W3C validation, you should remove the `width` attribute of the `div`s and use CSS achieve the same effect.
3. For stronger semantic, you can use HTML5 sectioning elements instead of `div`s.

   Like `<header>` instead of `<div id="header">`,

   `<main id="content">` instead of `<div id="content">`,

   and wrap your main navigation `<ul id="HomeMenu">` with `<nav>`
4. For more accessibility, you can add ARIA landmark roles to the tags mentioned above :

   ```
   <header role="banner">
   <nav role="navigation">
   <main id="content" role="main">
   ```

Comment: the width in the tags is a good one, I normally don't do that, I don't know why I did that this time.  as for the URL I am not too familiar with redirects on the server, but that is something that I would like to set up too, I think that is what makes this happen where the URL doesn't change when you change the pages.

Comment: of course I really don't like creating a class for one specific item though either, it makes more work for myself, so it it is one thing on one page then I would probably set the width in the HTML, because it isn't really styling it's structure.